# Course status template issue(lesson unit status)

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I'm making online courses platform in Wordpress using WPLMS theme. Problem is that when i open lesson, checkbox of this lesson automatically filled.
Or when i went to next lesson, checkbox of previous lesson automatically filled.
I need that only user can fill checkbox of lesson when he will decide to do it.
You can see menu of lessons on first image.[example of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZeZy.png)
I tried in settings choose a lot of options but it didn't help
Maybe i should reset progress of all lessons
[Options which i tried to change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AisEW.png)

Answer (score 0):

Disable auto-completion of units in WP admin - LMS - Settings.